# Stripe Embeddable pricing table - show active subscription plan

Tags: stripe-payments

Is there any way to show active subscription plan on stripe's embeddable table, like passing customer, subscription or price id?

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table

How on client side, where stripe pricing table is used, can be prevented for user/customer to select another (or same) plan and do any sort of action except updating current plan with upgrade or downgrade?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The pricing table product is built for first time purchases and it allows you to easily drop an iframe on your webpage that shows the different price options that you offer to your new customers. Once you have a [Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object) that has already made a purchase, the pricing table product is not what should be used.

Instead, separately, you can let your existing customers manage their subscriptions with the Customer Portal [here](https://stripe.com/docs/customer-management) which has a full Stripe redirect page. You can [pass](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/configurations/create#create_portal_configuration-features-subscription_update-products-prices) the list of Price ids when creating the portal configuration so your customers are able to upgrade or downgrade to different prices.

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer mentioned, you can't change the appearance of the pricing table to show which subscription is currently active.

However you can pass it a client-reference-id to track which user is requesting a checkout. This can be useful to sync your system with Stripe's.

> The  web component supports setting the client-reference-id property. When the property is set, the pricing table passes it to the Checkout Session’s client_reference_id attribute to help you reconcile the Checkout Session with your internal system. This can be an authenticated user ID or a similar string. client-reference-id can be composed of alphanumeric characters, dashes, or underscores, and be any value up to 200 characters. Invalid values are silently dropped and your pricing table will continue to work as expected.

[See this bit in the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table#handle-fulfillment-with-the-stripe-api)